# Dual Boot Assistance for Windows 11 Pro - Failing to See External USB as "Bootable Device"

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

I am experiencing issues with my laptop failing to read an external bootable USB as a "bootable device" when holding `shift` + `reboot` and upon entering the bootup menu.

**Device Details**
`Lenovo 21E6007QUS (x64) | Lenovo MT 21E6 BU Thinkpad E15 Gen 4` - `UEFI` boot mode

Windows 11 Pro is the base, factory image and hard drive encryption (BitLocker) is enabled by default from factory.

I followed all steps listed [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-linux-dual-booting-tutorial/) on how to dual boot Windows with any flavor or Linux. However, where it says "Now You Can Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows 10" in the guide, I am holding shift (a slightly different type of menu UI displayed) I tried all of the above options, but none work or actually represent the bootable USB stick pre-loaded with Kali Linux on.

I have tried:

- Disabling secure boot and entering the BitLocker key following prompts
- Physically connecting different USB sticks of A/C types in known working ports ports
- Created bootable USB sticks using both A/C types
- Created a bootable USB using [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher) and [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) with every method possible, I.E NTFS/FAT32 format etc.
  -- Rufus seems to allow for more granular configuration when creating the bootable USB

Any idea's hugely appreciated!

Comment: Some UEFI firmware has setting for allowing / disallowing USB booting particularly btw. May want to double check. Also, consider adding a photo of the boot menu you saw.

Comment: @John Stop bugging me. I did even get the chance to downvote your answer, but was only quick enough to see two others did. (I'm *surprised* that you didn't tell the OP to "just virtualize instead" this time btw.)